# Php mail. Can't get email on one address

Tags: php, email, send

I have a problem with my mail in php. I code form to send email. I receive email on gmail but I have other mail address and I can't get email on it.
I checked in spam and there is no email also.
Below is my code.

```
<?php
$emailErr =  "";
$endMessage = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Proszę uzupełnić pole e-mail";
} 
else if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
{
//send email
$namesurname = $_REQUEST['name_surname'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$number = $_REQUEST['number'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$message = $subject . ": " . $message . " " . $number . " " . $namesurname .     " " . $email;
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="; 
mail("szafor@szafor.pl", "Zamówienie pomiaru", 
$message, "From: formularz@szafortest.pl \r\n"."Content-Type: text/plain;     charset=UTF-8\r\n"); 
$endMessage = "Dziękuję za przesłanie wiadomości.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your second mail function?

Comment: You didn't use mime-encoded subject in your function. You shouldn't terminate the last additional header with "\r\n". This makes the message malformed.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to consider with sending mail is that you should at least have the return path of the message be an email address that is actually hosted on the server that you are sending from.

You can set the From and the Reply-To address as any address, but the return-path should be set to a valid email address hosted on your server. Let's say that you want the "reply" button to send back to "this_email@wherever.com" but the server you are using hosts email for "mydomain.com". Create an email account on your server, "info@mydomain.com" for example.

```
$recipient = "sendto@email.com";

$subject = "Test email";

$message = "This is the message.";

$headers .= "From: Your Name Here <any_email@wherever.com>\n\r";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Your Name Here <any_email@wherever.com>\n\r";
$headers .= "Return-Path: Your Name Here <info@mydomain.com>\n\r";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .="X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I have found that the more valid header information that I provide, the more likely the email will be delivered. Right now these headers always work for me, and I have a scheduling program that is sending email to a hundred different email addresses every day. See if that works better for you.